# Adjust ImageView width according to height

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple LinearLayout composed of an ImageView and TextView.

The ImageView should scale to match the LinearLayout height and not lose proportions while doing so.

This is the xml I currently have.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/strip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logoText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="what an awesome text"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using the above xml, the result is that the ImageView height will indeed match the LinearLayout height and it's width will be the same as the src image but the rendered image will scale properly and center, but this leaves the ImageView itself filling about 90% of the Layout's width as it's the src image width, leaving no space for the TextView.

I just would like to scale the ImageView to match the parent's height and it's width should be just as much needed to scale it proportionately.

Comment: Try changing scaleType to cropCenter

Comment: centerCrop will match the parent's height, the width issue persists and the image is cropped from the middle to fit the view. I need to fit the view, not cropping the image.

Comment: Put the image view in a linear layout. Just the image view. Nothing else.

Comment: I believe the issue here is related to the `wrap_content` in the ImageView width. Just don't know how to get around this since the inverted concept (scalling the height according to the width) works perfectly.

Comment: Try my other idea. It worked with a list view. No harm in trying

Comment: Damn.. That works... Having the LinearLayout scale around the TextView produces a really weird behaviour. Thank for the help. Thumbs up.

Comment: If it works please mark my answer as correct for reference of future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a linear layout on the image view. Just the image view and nothing else. :) hope it helps

**EDIT 1:** As many of the other answers mentioned Using the `layout_weight` property will also help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

add weight 1 on imageview so there will be space for the textview

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment under your answer post where you cite KISHORE_ZE, it seems to be helpful only with an image of particular size, and on a particular screen density and resolution. So while it looks acceptable on your current device, it might be a mess on a different one. I suggest that you figure out what part of the layout you want to use for the image and use `android:weight` attributes for your `ImageView` and `TextView` to achieve wanted result.

Comment: Sure no problem. But I think putting it in a linear layout will work. I know it worked with a list view. So I have a feeling it will work on all images. However as I mentioned I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

As @KISHORE_ZE said, this solves the problem.

"Put the image view in a linear layout. Just the image view. Nothing else. "

Comment: Can you please mark mine as correct? The checkmark. Thanks?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly does it fix the issue? What if you need some other image to show in the same layout while the image is twice as bigger? Three times bigger? How will it behave? I didn't check this solution, but I have a strong feeling that it only solves the problem for this particular image with a certain size, and what even more important, on a certain screen density. Try to set some bigger image to your ImageView and see how does it behave.

Answer (score 0):

this visual guide is a lot helpful.
[link](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide)

in your image view add:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

whichever suites you.